# How to select .bg-image:before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

I want to select something like

```
.bg-image:before {
```

in jQuery, but it is not working.

```
$(".bg-image:before").css("background-color","red");
```

How to select it?

Comment: post your HTML code too. Are you using framework like Bootstrap..?

Comment: Is this you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin